# C cash register

Tags: c

Hey guys, I'm still learning C and have created a virtual cash register. One problem, how do I display my output results after the total is calculated that's all the program renders. I also can't figure out how to instantiate a cashTendered method where the user will give the program (20.00 for example) and subtract that from it's total amount of the items Also, if you spot any additional errors and/or have any ideas, please let me know.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    // Instantiate the Variables    
    float itemPrice1 = 0, // Represents the item's price
          itemPrice2 = 0, // Represents secondary item price
          itemQuantity1 = 0, // Accounts for the specified quantity of the item
          itemQuantity2 = 0,
          subTotal1 = 0, // Amount prior to taxAmount 
          subTotal2 = 0,
          taxAmount = 0, // Percentage rate of 7% or 0.07
          totalAmount = 0, // Accounts for totalAmount including taxAmount
          cashTendered = 0, // Amount given towards totalAmount price
          change = 0; // Deductable given after payment

// Implementation 

    printf("Enter the quantity and price for Paint :");
    scanf("%f %f", &itemQuantity1, &itemPrice1);
    printf("Enter the quantity and price for Blue Brush :");
    scanf("%f %f", &itemQuantity2, &itemPrice2);



    subTotal1 = itemPrice1 * itemQuantity1; 
    subTotal2 = itemPrice2 * itemQuantity2; 
    taxAmount = 0.07*(subTotal1 + subTotal2);
    totalAmount = subTotal1 + subTotal2 + taxAmount;
    change = cashTendered - totalAmount;

// Program's output results

    printf("Your total is: %.2f", totalAmount);
    scanf("%f", totalAmount);
    printf ("Here is your receipt :\n");
    printf ("JcPenny Stores\t\t\n");
    printf ("Dayview Mall\t\t\n");
    printf ("Article 1\t\t\t 1 @", itemPrice1, subTotal1);
    printf ("Article 2\t\t\t 2 @", itemPrice2, subTotal2);
    printf("Sub Total\t\t%.2f\n", subTotal1+subTotal2);
    printf("Sales Tax(7%%)\t\t%.2f\n", taxAmount);
    printf("Total Amount\t\t\t%.2f\n", totalAmount);
    printf("Cash Tendered\t\t\t%.2f\n", cashTendered);
    printf("Change\t%.2f\n\n", change);
    printf("Thank you for shopping with us!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why didn't you use a struct for the items?

Comment: Why are you doing `scanf("%f", totalAmount);` after that first `printf()` in the output block? Also, it should be `&totalAmount`.

Comment: try to use at least 'long double' in you money variables

Comment: @chrisaycock For some reason it wouldn't display the total I'm not sure why. I'm going to edit it in just a minute and feedback would be appreciated. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Questions

### cashTendered method

You can't create a (simple) cashTendered method (as a void function) with the current layout because all of your variables are only visible inside the scope of the `main` function. You would need to either pass all of your data to the cashTendered method (making structs would make this significantly less painful- see below) or make all of your variables global (generally considered to be a bad idea, for a number of complicated reasons).

## Suggestions

### Combining

An item should be a struct, with members `price` and `quantity` (both should be `int`s: see "Numeric Types" below). Subtotal doesn't really need to be a member of the item structure, as it's a property of the total transaction and not the item.

## Mistakes

### Numeric types

You should really be using integers rather than floats for your prices, since you're not counting a *fractional amount* of dollars but an *integral number* of cents (all dollar prices should be multiplied by 100).

For example, when you mark a $10.00 item down by a third, you want your new price to be $6.66, not $6.666666666666. While printf will adjust your output to two places, it won't adjust your underlying math- it will report that somebody paying $6.66 won't be giving enough money (since they'll be short two-thirds of a cent).

There are other issues you'll run into since float is not a [decimal floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point) type (6.66 - (6.65 + 0.01) may not equal zero, for instance).

Comment: The accountants (and revenue agents) get all kinds of upset when you start shaving off fractions.

Comment: In scenarios where the fractions of a cent matter, you can use decimal floating point (and for such critical operations here you can use floats for the duration of the operation). For this application, there's more to be lost from storing the values as base-2 floats than there is with integers.

Comment: Great post, I understand what you're saying with the underlying math. I'm going to refactor this and edit it in. Should take 20-30 minutes and you can take a look at what I've done. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

On some Operating Systems, the program's output is displayed in a window.  As soon as the program finishes, the window disappears.

One method to prevent this is to prompt the User to press "ENTER" to continue or end the program.